# Scrolls up when submitting question even though there is no error

Tags: bug

When I'm writing a question, after I'm done I click the submit button and then I get scrolled up. I search around for the error but it doesn't seem like there is one, I click submit again and it works.

Seems like a strange behaviour. It would be expected if there was an error in submitting such as a missing tag or whatever.

Comment: There's an automatic review process that occurs before your question is submitted. On the right side of the page, it'll detail whether your question has passed this review and you can continue on and post. You'll notice that the button's label is "Review Your Question" and changes to "Submit Question" when you've passed the review. The first press will scroll you to the top, which would call attention to any errors if there were any, and (I imagine) encourages you the asker to give your question one more glance over before posting.

Comment: It just seems very weird to scroll the user back up when there's no issue. Lots of sites do this but only if there's an error, like you missed a mandatory page, so I'm just spending time looking for a red error.

Comment: It's also going to condition the regular users to just scroll back down and click again right away. Which if there is an error means it will scroll up again, wasting even more time and effort.